# SetInterval/SetTimeout halted after sleep

Tags: javascript, jquery

The refresh cycle of my script with either Interval or Timeout is only firing arbitrarily after coming back from sleep. How would I fix this?

Comment: Be more specific, come back from what enviroment? Desktop? Mobile? Show me your code

Comment: Desktop. If the OS wakes up and a AJAX-call is made right after that, JS throws a "Failed to load resource" and halts, because the network isn't ready yet. I need to have JS retry after a while. JQuery's ajax error condition won't help.

Answer (score 0):

Consider debug your app using `$.ajaxSetup` - you need discover the error code and implement some routine to re-gain your session!

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    error: function(e, x, settings, exception) {
        console.warn(e, 'e');
        console.warn(x, 'x');
        console.warn(settings, 'settings');
        console.warn(exception, 'exception');
    }
});
```